# db2- Set the default value with the next sequence value

Tags: db2

How I can set the default value for an attribute to be the next value of a squeuence

I tried the following :

```
ALTER TABLE Person ADD COLUMN ccn VARCHAR(254) default (next value for KAP.CCN_SEQ );
```

And this cause a syntax error

Could you please advice is this doable and if yes what is the correct syntax ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column is of type Varchar - I assume this is a bit unusual for a sequence number. You also need to determine whether you want to create an Identity or a Sequence. For difference between the two and how to create each see: [ID vs Sequence in DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/t0004990.htm). Some of the points to note are (as quoted from the ref.):
An identity column has the following characteristics:

•   An identity column can be defined as part of a table only when the table is created. Once a table is created, you cannot alter it to add an identity column. (However, existing identity column characteristics may be altered.)

•   An identity column automatically generates values for a single table.

•   When an identity column is defined as GENERATED ALWAYS, the values used are always generated by the database manager. Applications are not allowed to provide their own values during the modification of the contents of the table.

A sequence object has the following characteristics:

•   A sequence object is a database object that is not tied to any one table.

•   A sequence object generates sequential values that can be used in any SQL statement.

•   Since a sequence object can be used by any application, there are two expressions used to control the retrieval of the next value in the specified sequence and the value generated previous to the statement being executed. The PREVVAL expression returns the most recently generated value for the specified sequence for a previous statement within the current session. The NEXTVAL expression returns the next value for the specified sequence. The use of these expressions allows the same value to be used across several SQL statements within several tables.

To create a sequence (example):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ccn
      START WITH 1
      INCREMENT BY 1
      NOMAXVALUE
      NOCYCLE
      CACHE 24
```

Comment: Thanks Emmad For ur response :)

Comment: I Tried to make an identity but i can define the identity for an attribute in the create of the table not altering the table so that is why i switched to use a sequence

Comment: Is there any solution to set the value of the attribute to be the next sequence value ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: You could use identity if you create a new table and copy the data. This (may be) simple. You can use the sequence value if you create the sequence and you do: INSERT INTO person(PersonKey, otherdata)
     VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR ccn, 1000); As of now I don't have access of DB2, please try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much Emmad :) I created a procedure instead :)